# How to make Oracle and SQL Server ORDER BY the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need to compare table counts for an Oracle schema to a SQL Server database. However, when I make my query, the results are always off because of the way each handles the underscore ('_') in terms of ordering.  I've included an example of what I'm seeing below.

In Oracle:

```
SELECT FIELD1 FROM ORACLE_ORDER ORDER BY FIELD1 ASC;

Result:
'ABC'
'ABCD'
'ABC_D'
```

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT FIELD1 FROM SQL_ORDER ORDER BY FIELD1 ASC;

Result:
'ABC'
'ABC_D'
'ABCD'
```

As you can see from above, oracle and sql server both treat the underscore differently when it comes to ordering.  How can I modify either of the queries (or environments) to make them order the same as the other?

Comment: It seems the collations you are using are different. If you are using default collations, maybe you should add them explicitly.

Comment: But then the question is "What collation in SQL Server is compatible with a collation in Oracle?"

Comment: @Martin Smith, that needs to be found by the OP. First find what collation in SQL Server, then the equivalent one which should be in oracle, and when using the  oracle field, that has to be converted to.

Comment: Maybe convert the column to binary, varbinary?  Don't have access to an Oracle system, so I can't try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SQL Server Side use the following

```
Select * from SQL_ORDER  
ORDER BY FIELD1  Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN
```

The collation  SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN makes it to be used with ASCII values. In this case ASCII of underscore is 95, A being 65, and Z being 90. Remember lower case "a" will have a higher value than upper case "A" and so on.

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2671ebc8fc4f0b03c6ed9903c448d403)

Comment: thanks, you saved me a few hours of work every month!

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to use `Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN` function in `ORDER BY` to achieve this

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 'ABC' AS TAB UNION
SELECT'ABC_D'UNION
SELECT'ABCD'UNION
SELECT'ABC_'UNION
SELECT 'ABC' UNION
SELECT'A_C' UNION
SELECT'ABC_DE_FGH'UNION
SELECT'ABCXDEYFGH') AS X 
ORDER BY X.Tab Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN
```

Comment: That might work for tables like the example I made, but how does it work for tables with significantly more rows.

Comment: @Thiyagu - So how does that handle 'ABC' vs 'A_C'  or 'ABC_DE_FGH' vs 'ABCXDEYFGH'.  I'm afraid your proposed solution is overly simplistic.